# Using Vuex as well as an Event Bus in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex, event-bus

I've had this question buried in my mental Rolodex for quite some time now. I'm running a very complex Vue application that deals with quite a number of components that must communicate so for that I use a very structured setup of `Vuex` utilizing its `module` system. However, for a particular group of components, say a `comments` folder, i.e:

Comments Directory:

- Comments.vue  // overall comments component
- Comment.vue // component for each comment
- NewComment.vue // component to create new comments
- bus.js // reserved event bus for only these three components

Is it fine to utilize a reserved `Event Bus` placed in this directory only for these 3 components to communicate to one other, or is that deemed as "malpractice" since I already have a large vuex system going ?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Non-flux-state-management-use-with-caution . But if you know what you are doing, it's really up to you

Comment: I just feel as Vuex should be used for app wide communications, not for communications between 2-3 neighboring components... Im pretty satisfied with this implementation however, thanks for the link! @JacobGoh

Comment: @MikeStrong It's fine to use event bus even if you are using Vuex in your application. But, you know, since vuex is designed for communicating between all of the components available, I don't see the use of event bus that relevant. But it's up to you, btw!

Comment: My thing is, Vuex is global. Say I have 20 comments components->each have 10 comment components... why/how would i use vuex to allow each unique child->parent to communicate to each other? all mutations for each parent->child pair would overlap one another since the state is shared by all components... @Sanjay

Comment: Why do you feel a need to use an event bus, and not normal Vue events, in the first place, especially if these components have direct parent-child relation as you just explained? Just use normal events.

Comment: well because its slightly more complicated, you see my app has a global lightbox that is triggered when a posts' images are clicked and all that post data populates the lightbox including comments. So when the comments are updated both lightbox and post should get updates. I'll be using Vuex for everything, i was just curious @LinusBorg

Answer (score 13):

I suggest using Vuex for all of your application. Doing so keeps your state in a *single* place. Using an event bus detracts from this, in that now you have two places containing state. Worse still, an event bus is less maintainable and often breaks the "one way data flow" promoted by Vue and Vuex (and other Flux implementations).

Vuex can be used for both *application state* and *application data*. Data being the usual stuff like customer details, etc. State being the "this sidebar hamburger menu is open" or "this modal is open" or "user selected this item in a list".

This then leads on to your "I just feel as Vuex should be used for app wide communications, not for communications between 2-3 neighbouring components". It's the same thing when you think about it.

If a parent component wishes to communicate with a child component, it passes props down. If the child wishes to communicate in a **decoupled** manner it emits events. That is perfectly fine for that scenario.

Try doing that with multiple nested components! `A -> B -> C -> D`

Imagine if D needed to update some state in B. How do you do that, emit events all the way up, and couple your components? Yuck, that is not the way to go. D should dispatch a Vuex action which in turn updates B via the store binding. What about when A needs to updated something in C? Now your B component needs special case extra props just to allow A to communicate with C when B should be able to exist on it's own without A as a parent. Yuck again! Dispatch an action.

Communicating between sibling components or even components in totally different parts of the page is *exactly* one of the things Vuex is designed for: application state.

Removing your event bus and accepting this approach will make your code easier and more maintainable.

Comment: yes i understand that, prior to this little inquiry my entire app was vuex managed. Heres the scenario. We land on users profile, fetch user posts and store in vuex->update ui, no problem. however what about each posts comments and replies? storing all of them in one state object seems a little quirky

Comment: That's not quirky and exactly how it's supposed to work. An array of posts and child posts. This is the point of state management.

Comment: @user9993 this is very neat explanation. All i wanted to know, this just cleared every point i had in my mind related to state management. Thanks

Comment: @Bsienn You're welcome, glad it helped! Don't forget to check the Vue discord too.

Comment: How to use vuex only to emit event? not to change state data? And how i react to any unchangable data, i want only react to some event using vuex

Comment: "How to use vuex only to emit event?" <= this is exactly what I'm looking for as well! In million of articles and threads all over the internet everyone is saying that EventBus is sub-optimal and can/should be replaced by Vuex, but if it comes to simple event notification without any state/data/change, there is no single example how to do this. E.g. using Vuex actions to $emit something, like a button click inside a custom debugger-console/helper should send an event, where multiple independent components can listen for.

Answer (score 0):

if your application is very complex and big than go with vuex which is better for the state management, if not than you can stick with props,event bus and all this.